# how to print the elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print the elements of this array, but it is printing junk characters. What is the problem in this program?

```
class Demo{     
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] x= new int []{5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
        {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! It'd be helpful is you pasted any output or errors your program is making, in this case it'd help if you put the "junk characters" :)

Comment: use Arrays.asList(x) also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Arrays.toString()` method:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
```

This gives you a meaningful representation of the data inside your array. The default `toString` of Java array objects is not a meaningful representation of the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
         int[] x= new int[]{5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
         {
             System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
         }
    }
```